# Reading stata data after RStudio update to version 1.0.143

Tags: r, rstudio, label, levels

although my problem appears to be very straight forward after days of looking for a solution the following basic code does not allow me to read in a dta file after I updated R studio to version 1.0.143

```
library(foreign)
library(MASS)
library(plyr)
library(zoo)
library(lmtest)
library(erer)
data <- read.dta("...")
```

I receive the following error message:

> ```
> Error in `levels<-`(`*tmp*`, value = if (nl == nL) as.character(labels) else paste0(labels,  : 
>   factor level [192] is duplicated
> ```

Indeed I found a few similar problems here. However the proposed solutions did not work for me.

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you know the Stata version from which your *.dta file was created?

Comment: Eventually, the argument convert.factors = FALSE in read.dta enabled to read the data. However, with this I receive integer variables, which previously were strings. Do you have an idea how to change this?